# How to add jstree to angular 2 application using typescript with @types/jstree

Tags: angular, typescript, jstree

Hi I believe it's some kind of a newbee question, but I'm new to ng2 so please bear with me...

I've done:

```
npm i jstree --save
```

After I created using angular-cli application.

Then I installed:

```
npm i @types/jstree --save-dev
```

And that's on setup, then I tried to use it and no luck.

Please can someone show me how to use that 3rd party library with typescript

Comment: [3rd Party Library Installation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib)

Comment: @R.Richards doesn't work

Comment: Have you checked your package.json? .... If it contains @types/jstree in dependencies array than your 3rd party library is installed. Otherwise type manually "@types/jstree":"x.x.x"(version) and run npm install.

Comment: @ShreenilPatel Dude I've done it. It's not the first project I do. But it's doesn't load any of the jstree.min.js dependencies

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are the steps I took to get it to work.
I started with a new cli application.

`npm install --save jquery jstree`

`npm install --save-dev @types/jquery @types/jstree`

I then updated the `angular.json` file, if you are using an older version of angular-cli, makes changes to the `angular-cli.json` file. I added `"../node_modules/jstree/dist/themes/default-dark/style.min.css"` to the styles property array.

I also added two items into the scripts property array:

`"../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
"../node_modules/jstree/dist/jstree.min.js"`

I then updated `src/app/app.component.html` to

```
<div id="foo">
  <ul>
    <li>Root node 1
      <ul>
        <li>Child node 1</li>
        <li><a href="#">Child node 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I also update `src/app/app.component.ts` to

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit(): void {
    $('#foo').jstree();
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is so useful for other jQuery components too!

Comment: Its not working properly : https://stackblitz.com/edit/jstree-demo
Can you help , where i am wrong ?

Comment: @N.K Honestly, I'm not sure...sorry. I do have a full repo on [GitHub](https://github.com/PdUi/stack-overflow-answer-repos/tree/master/ng-jstree) that might help you though. It has two ways of accomplishing this. One is similar to my answer above(all of the relevant lines are commented out). The uncommented out version though is probably the more correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

@IamStalker, it seems that i know what the problem is. But can you present more code to show how you want to use it?

---

As jstree depends on jQuery, you have to import it too.

You may have to use `scripts` config.

Here is the reference: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts.