# JsTree gives Property 'jstree' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>' in Angular 4

Tags: angular, jstree

I am using Angular 4 and I want to work with [JsTree](https://www.jstree.com) in my application. I integrated JsTree into my Angular app like in this answer : [How to add jstree to angular 2 application using typescript with @types/jstree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44987260/how-to-add-jstree-to-angular-2-application-using-typescript-with-types-jstree)

When I run `ng serve` I get the following error

```
ERROR in D:/VsCodeProjects/float-client/src/app/dashboard/budget-setup/budget-setup.component.ts (27,15): Property 'jstree' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.

ERROR in D:/VsCodeProjects/float-client/src/app/dashboard/budget-setup/budget-setup.component.ts (27,15): Property 'jstree' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.
```

> In component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    $('#foo').jstree();
}
```

> In component.html

```
<div id="foo">
  <ul>
    <li>Root node 1
      <ul>
        <li>Child node 1</li>
        <li><a href="#">Child node 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Does jstree still support Angular 4**? If supports, what am I missing here?

Comment: Please check this:- https://medium.com/@NetanelBasal/typescript-integrate-jquery-plugin-in-your-project-e28c6887d8dc

Comment: already installed @types/jquery

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44987260/how-to-add-jstree-to-angular-2-application-using-typescript-with-types-jstree

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:-

```
  let elem: any;
    elem = $("#foo");
    elem.jstree();
```

Comment: I get TypeError: elem.jstree is not a function  in browser console. I have already included the scripts and styles in the angular-cli.json